# apns-csharp certificate trouble

Tags: asp.net, .net, apple-push-notifications

I trying to use apns-csharp library to send push notification from .NET, I created certificate on Apple Provision Portal, download it and convert to p12 format, when i try to load it with code:

```
private ActionResult SendAlertPushNotification(string appId, string notificationContent, bool useSandBox)
        {
            NotificationService notificationService = new NotificationService(useSandBox,ApplicationsRepository.GetAPNSCertificateForApplication(appId,useSandBox),"123",1);
            notificationService.ReconnectDelay = 2000;
            notificationService.Error += new NotificationService.OnError(service_Error);
            notificationService.NotificationTooLong += new NotificationService.OnNotificationTooLong(service_NotificationTooLong);

            notificationService.BadDeviceToken += new NotificationService.OnBadDeviceToken(service_BadDeviceToken);
            notificationService.NotificationFailed += new NotificationService.OnNotificationFailed(service_NotificationFailed);
            notificationService.NotificationSuccess += new NotificationService.OnNotificationSuccess(service_NotificationSuccess);
            notificationService.Connecting += new NotificationService.OnConnecting(service_Connecting);
            notificationService.Connected += new NotificationService.OnConnected(service_Connected);
            notificationService.Disconnected += new NotificationService.OnDisconnected(service_Disconnected);
            var devices = ApplicationsRepository.GetPushClientDevicesID(appId);
            foreach (var token in devices)
            {
                var notification = new Notification(token);
                notification.Payload.Alert.Body = notificationContent;
                notification.Payload.Sound = "default";
                notification.Payload.Badge = 1;
                //Queue the notification to be sent
                if (notificationService.QueueNotification(notification))
                    Debug.WriteLine("Notification Queued!");
                else
                    Debug.WriteLine("Notification Failed to be Queued!");
            }
            notificationService.Close();
            ViewData["app"] = ApplicationsRepository.GetApplicationByAppId(appId);
            ViewData["count"] = devices.Count;
            return View("SendSuccess");
        }
```

I receive internal error when try to load a certificate. If i use original certificate if .cer format, i dont receive any exceptions but nothing is actually sended to APNS servers. Has anyone encountered this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that you have exported the right certificate. I recently encountered a similar problem only to find that I exported the wrong one.

> **OSX Keychain** 
>   After you've created the
>   appropriate Push Notification
>   Certificate in iPhone Developer
>   Program Portal you should have
>   downloaded a file named something like
>   apn_developer_identity.cer. If you
>   have not done so already, you should
>   open/import this file into Keychain,
>   into your login section.
>
> Finally, if you filter Keychain to
>   show your login container's
>   Certificates, you should see your
>   Certificate listed. Expand the
>   certificate, and there should be a Key
>   underneath/attached to it.
>
> Right Click or Ctrl+Click on the
>   appropriate Certificate and choose
>   Export. Keychain will ask you to
>   choose a password to export to. Pick
>   one and remember it. You should end up
>   with a .p12 file. You will need this
>   file and the password you picked to
>   use the Notification and Feedback
>   Libraries here.
>
> **Source [How To Create a PKCS12 Certificate](http://code.google.com/p/apns-sharp/wiki/HowToCreatePKCS12Certificate)**

*I'm sure by now that you have solved this one way or the other, but having just been through this my self, I thought it might be good to put down my experience.*

Comment: Thanks @ashansky - it took me awhile to figure out how to do this - your directions are spot on.